# Apache Archiva internal repo suddenly just hangs

Tags: download, freeze, archiva

The internal repo suddenly gave up. All the artifacts are there and can be browsed through the browser but if you actually click on an artifact or a pom to download it it hangs.

Jenkins uses Archiva as well and suddenly can no longer fetch new artifacts from the internal repo. All we get is this 500 error: 500 , ReasonPhrase:Unable to fetch artifact resource

The internal repo mirrors maven central.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have anything in the logs file to help? archiva.log file

Comment: Well yes but there's not a single error in any of them...

Comment: any thread dump? use jstack

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're out of hard drive space or your server's internet connection to the outside isn't operational?

A restart of Archiva may do the trick if not.